# Updating Hyperlink Address on Load Microsoft Access

Tags: hyperlink, ms-access-2007

I have a form in an Access 2007 database and I need to automatically update the Hyperlink Address when the form loads to add an ID number at the end (when the form loads, it loads an ID from the table. This ID needs to be added at the end of the Hyperlink). Basically, whenever the form loads, I need it to dynamically create that Hyperlink Address based off of the ID field.

For instance:

Before load: `URL=`
After load: `URL=1`

Where 1 is the currently selected ID from the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access supports several "events" that are triggered when a form is opened. One of those is the `Load` event which fires when the form is first loaded. For details, look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211406%28v=office.11%29.aspx).

You could add some code to the `Form_Load` event handler to update the string in question, something like...

```
myHyperlink = myHyperlink & [ID]
```

...which would happen once, when the form first loads. If you want the hyperlink to be updated as you move between records (while the form is open) then you could use the `Current` event instead, and use something like

```
myBaseHyperlink = "http://example.com/id="
myHyperlink = myBaseHyperlink & [ID]
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the Form_Load event seeing as there is no way to navigate records on the form in question. Worked great